# macrodef'd <jar> task not behaving like an implicit fileset?

Tags: ant

Using standard Ant 1.9.7 to assemble a bunch of jar files.  We've made a macro to help cut down on the verbosity of the XML:

```
<!-- All 'description' bits snipped for SO posting. -->
<macrodef name="buildjar">
  ... bunch of <attribute> ...
  <element name="also"/>
  <sequential>
    <jar ....>
      <manifest>  ...  </manifest>
      <fileset what="stuff in every jar file" />
      <fileset what="and this stuff too" />
      <mappedresources if:true="beauty">
        <fileset for when truth is beauty/>
        <globmapper from="ugly" to="beauty"/>
      </mappedresoruces>

      <!-- Anything else for this specific jar. -->
      <also/>

    </jar>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This works:

```
<buildjar .........>
  <also>
    <fileset file="/some/path/somewhere/a_single_file"/>
  </also>
</buildjar>
```

But this does not:

```
<buildjar .........>
  <also>
    <include name="/some/path/somewhere/a_single_file"/>
  </also>
</buildjar>
```

There are no errors.  Looking at `ant -d` output, there's no mention of the additional entry at all, where in the first example there is a line for `fileset: Setup scanner in dir /some/path/somewhere with patternSet{ includes: [a_single_file] excludes: [] }`

Ditto for multiple files.  This works:

```
<buildjar .........>
  <also>
    <fileset dir="/some/path/somewhere">
      <include name="one_file" />
      <include name="foo**" />
    </fileset>
  </also>
</buildjar>
```

but this does not:

```
<buildjar .........>
  <also>
    <include name="/some/path/somewhere/one_file"/>
    <include name="/some/path/somewhere/foo**"/>
  </also>
</buildjar>
```

According to the Ant manual's page for `<jar>`,

> This task forms an **implicit FileSet** and supports most attributes of <fileset> (dir becomes basedir) as well as the **nested <include>**, <exclude> and <patternset> elements.

So in theory, shouldn't an `<include>` simply be enough, and become a nested element of the macro'd `<jar>`?

Obviously, in practice this isn't a problem (we slap a bigass comment in the build files telling people to not leave out the explicit `<fileset>`).  And we can't put the `<fileset>` into the macro definition like this:

```
<macrodef name="buildjar">
  <element name="also"/>
  <sequential>
    <jar ....>
      .....
      <!-- Anything else for this specific jar. -->
>>    <fileset dir="some_generic_base_path">
        <also/>
>>    </fileset>
    </jar>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

because then when the calling code does a `buildjar` *without* any `also` blocks, the unrestricted fileset will include the entire `some_generic_base_path` tree.

Is this simply some interaction between macrodefs and filesets that has taken us by surprise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no - it's not a macrodef problem.  To use the implicit fileset you must specify the `basedir` attribute for the `<jar>` task.  Here's an example that illustrates this:

```
<jar destfile="my.jar">
    <include name="a/b" />
</jar>

<zip destfile="my.zip" >
    <include name="a/b" />
</zip>
```

In the example the `<jar>` task will succeed and create a manifest-only jar file.  But the `<zip>` task will fail saying:

```
BUILD FAILED
build.xml:8: basedir attribute must be set, or at least one resource collection must be given!
```

The jar task is based on the zip task and inherits its check for resources.  Because the jar task has some - the manifest - the error is not thrown.

If you want to use the implicit fileset, specify a `basedir`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's not mentioned in the manual entry for the `<jar>` task.  Unfortunately, specifying `basedir` does more than set the starting point for relative paths; it also jars up the entire specified directory tree, with the nested `include`s being treated as duplicates rather than refinements.  We'll just avoid the implicit filesets for now, and this will hold us over until we can get away from Ant.